# Ubuntu Bower Install Issue

Tags: ubuntu, bower

I have followed the guide here to install Bower on Ubuntu 14.04.1
http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/installing-bower-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

And it looks like it installed fine

```
. /usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
```

BUT when I try to run bower I get no response.

```
t@t:~$ bower install bootstrap
t@t:~$ bower list
t@t:~$ bower search
t@t:~$ bower -version
```

What am I missing ?

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here -> `https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/201`

Problem was confusion between node and nodejs

- sudo apt-get remove node
- sudo apt-get remove nodejs
- sudo apt-get install nodejs
- sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Now all working perfectly :-) YEAH!!!!!